# What are compensation rules for overbooked/cancelled flights for different regions?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, overbooking

What regulations are applicable for overbooked/cancelled flights around the globe?

I travel from time to time in Europe and there is [EU 261/2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004) regarding overbooked and cancelled flights. Is there any alternative legislation or regulations per Country/Region/Airline?

I did research on the web, `travel.stackexchange.com` and wikipedia but didn't find any clear information for regions different from EU.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad. AFAIK, the EU regulation is the only case where common compensation rules are in effect in several countries. Since there are more than 150 non-EEA countries, each likely with different regulations for compensation, it is not possible to answer this question as asked.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Do you propose to create 150+ questions for each separate country? Do you have any suggestions how to improve this question? I am interested in 10-20 countries only, I thought it could be regional guidelines for such cases which I simply couldn't find.

Comment: If you are interested in only a few countries I suggest you edit to ask only about those countries.